# Supermicro SmartOS setup issue with HDDs

Tags: configuration, supermicro, smartos

I'm trying to setup SmartOS on my new Supermicro server (SYS-6027R-N3RF4+).  I have 8 HDDs + 2 SSDs installed in the hot-swappable drive bays.  I have not configured the Intel RAID controller on the machine (it shows no RAID configured, and lists all 8 HDDs).

When I boot SmartOS from my USB key for the first time and get to the initial zpool creation I only see 2 disks listed.

How can I tell which two drives are being referenced?  How can I get SmartOS to recognize all 8+2 drives?  Is there a BIOS setting I need to adjust?

Comment: You'll probably have to checkout what the Intel SAS Configuration has to say. I'm not sure if it'll be in the BIOS or a separate F-Button during POST, but it should be in one of those two places.

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can get more information on detected disks, It will help you find which disk isn't recognized:

1. Boot smartos
2. "Would you like to continue with configuration? [Y/n]" --> answer n
3. Login with root, the default password can be found in the file SINGLE_USER_ROOT_PASSWORD.txt next to the iso image you're using.

   For example on https://us-east.manta.joyent.com//Joyent_Dev/public/SmartOS/20131102T215831Z/SINGLE_USER_ROOT_PASSWORD.txt where 20131102T215831Z is the build identifier.

   You can find the build identifier on the login screen below the Joyent logo.
4. once you're logged in run:

   ```
   $ diskinfo
   ```

   you should see all disks detected by smartos